# Update Array Elements from other elements in Pymongo and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have an document collection that has the following fields and others:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("xxxxx")
Allocations: [
    { _id: ObjectId("xxxx"), Allocation_Acin: 48, cf_od: 10 }
    { _id: ObjectId("xxxx"), Allocation_Acin: 52, cf_od: 5  }
    ]
 _nrd: "SP"
 }
```

Within that collection we need to run an update to preform `Allocation_Acin - cf_od` and replace `Allocation_Acin` with the result.

I have tried the following:

```
try:
     result = db.flowmeters.update_many({'_nrd': 'SP'}, 
                                   [{'$set': { "Allocations.$.Allocation_Acin": 
                                    {'$subtract': ['$Allocations.$.Allocation_Acin' 
                                                   '$Allocations.$.cf_od']}
                                    }}])
except error.PyMongoError as e:
    logging.error(f'MongoDB error: {e}')
```

I receive the error: "Invalid $set :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'"

My expected result is:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("xxxxx")
Allocations: [
    { _id: ObjectId("xxxx"), Allocation_Acin: 38, cf_od: 10 }
    { _id: ObjectId("xxxx"), Allocation_Acin: 47, cf_od: 5  }
    ]
 _nrd: "SP"
 }
```

Comment: I don't think the positional operator can be used like that

Comment: Yes, it really doesn't like to used that way, and I wonder if I have to approach this in a whole different method.